# Show Null Values in Count Statement - SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I am developing a sales report and trying to select the count of Activities Done by the Sales Person during the week and want to show all Activities regardless he have done it or No in a table, i am using a left or full join but not showing. below is the explanation of Tables

```
Table 1: Activity Types - ACT_TYPE_ID ,ACT_TYPE_Desc 
Table 2: Activity Details - ACT_TYPE_ID, ACT_TYPE_Text
```

I want to show it as below:

Type                   Count

```
Sales Call -             3 
Phone Call               0 
Meeting Outside          9
```

Below is my select statement but not returning the required and showing only activities that is created:

```
Select ACT_TYPE_Desc as [Activity Type] , Count(CR031_DIARY_TEXT) as Count 
From ACT_TYPES AT  Join ACT_Details AD 
On AT.DRY_TRC_TYPE = Ad.ACT_TYPE 
Group By ACT_TYPE_Desc
```

This solution almost works, but it doesn't show activities that are not assigned Are there any way to include those activities, i have used Left and full join

Please let me know if you need more information.

Thanx

Comment: `Group By  ACT_TYPE_Desc ` is a good start. (You typically GROUP BY the columns you select, except those who are arguments to set functions.)

Comment: Just use a LEFT JOIN instead of JOIN.

Comment: Still not showing the null values. specially if i am adding a where clause with a period of time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a left join, and count a column from the `ACT_Details` table, to include all records in the count, even `NULL`s:

```
SELECT
    AT.ACT_TYPE_Desc AS [Activity Type],
    COUNT(AD.ACT_TYPE) AS cnt
FROM ACT_TYPES AT
LEFT JOIN ACT_Details AD
    ON AT.DRY_TRC_TYPE = AD.ACT_TYPE AND <restriction on time>
GROUP BY
    AT.ACT_TYPE_Desc;
```

Note on the `<restriction on time>`:

If you need to add any restrictions on the `ACT_Details` table, then place them in the `ON` clause of the join.  Restrictions on the `ACT_TYPES` table may go in a `WHERE` clause.

Comment: Still not showing the null values. specially if i am adding a where clause with a period of time

Comment: @OsamaAshraf Check my updated answer.  You never showed your full schema.  Not necessarily a bad thing, except when you refer to columns about which we don't know.  I suggest adding your time check in the `ON` clause of the join.

Comment: Thank for your reply, apologize for missing the time, i worked now when i have added all my restrictions in the On clause and not in the where clause. Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can try below

```
Select ACT_TYPE_Desc as [Activity Type] , Count(CR031_DIARY_TEXT) as Count 
From ACT_TYPES AT left Join ACT_Details AD 
On AT.DRY_TRC_TYPE = Ad.ACT_TYPE 
Group By ACT_TYPE_Desc
```

Comment: Still not showing the null values. specially if i am adding a where clause with a period of time

Answer (score 0):

Try like this :

```
Select COALESCE(ACT_TYPE_Desc, 'Empty') as [Activity Type] , 
COALESCE(Count(CR031_DIARY_TEXT), 0) as Count

From ACT_TYPES AT LEFT OUTER Join 

ACT_Details AD 
On AT.DRY_TRC_TYPE = Ad.ACT_TYPE 
Group By CR774_DRY_TRC_DESC
```

the Coalesce function will return 0 when the value is null. Attantion, The return value (in this case 'empty') is depends on the returning value. It can be a string or a date or any other type depending on the column type.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way is using the left outer join, in the left outer join the left table is join at the right when if the left row hasn't a corrispondent row with the right table will exist in the join with the columns of right table at null, this is different fron the inner join ( your join )
This is the documentation of left join https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp
and this is the documentation of the inner join https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp

```
Select ACT_TYPE_Desc as [Activity Type] , Count(CR031_DIARY_TEXT) as Count 
From ACT_TYPES AT  LEFT Join ACT_Details AD 
On AT.DRY_TRC_TYPE = Ad.ACT_TYPE 
Group By ACT_TYPE_Desc
```

Comment: it doesnt work with the Left, i am not sure what is missing, i want firstly to list all activities and then count them in a specific time.

Comment: have you tried to use the with, you can concentrate yourself to find the list and use the tablelike a view temporary https://modern-sql.com/feature/with like this
with V ( SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE ) 
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM V GROUP BY